# remove count from google plus in sociable plugin

Tags: wordpress, social-networking

I am using `sociable plugin` in my wordpress blog posts. I need to `hide count` from google plus. I found this code `<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:count="false"></a>` But i don't know where to use this one.

[image]

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the share button on the front end you should see a div with a class of "vC".  You should be able to hide the count by setting it as a display:none in your css.

```
.vC { display:none; }
```

If it's not in "vC" you can replace the class with the what is on your site.

Comment: Can i do this using script?